# ITMS-90037 The Info.plist file is missing or could not be parsed while app store submittion

Tags: ios, app-store, plist

When I upload the app into app store, I got the mail from itunese connect with the following issue

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "***". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>   This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file is missing or could not be parsed. Please check it for embedded control characters.
>   Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

I have checked the info.plist file path, created the new plist , but I couldn't succeed. have any idea ?

Comment: You'll have to post the contents as there is not enough information otherwise.

Comment: have u validate ur app before uploading. if u have validate app it might give u error.

Comment: @vaibby yes, I've validated and tried with both xcode upload and application loader upload.

Comment: @trojanfoe no, this is the mail content which I received from itunes connect. you mean, I've to post my plist file content ?

Answer (score 9):

For me, I had a non visible control character in the file. I edited the file using `vi` and deleted the invalid character and then everything worked.

Comment: Thanks. I had a control character in the build number field somehow. :-/

Answer (score 1):

[image]plist is normal xml which stores property or information of app. it seem like plist files is not formatted properly or plist file might be deleted by incidentally.

go to build settings -> packaging -> info.plist File put location of plist (example - Project_folder/Info.plist)

set YES in Expand Build settings in info plist file

set binary in info.plist output encoding

Comment: Yes I've set plist path at  build settings. But I couldn't understand your last two steps. what does it mean for set YES in Expand Build settings in plist file ?

Comment: This was not effective for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

go to BuildSetting -> Packaging -> Info.plist File in PROJECT
If its area is not empty, clear string.

Comment: It's unclear what string you're talking about clearing.  Nothing I did here was effective.

Answer (score 0):

I wrestled many hours with this issue before I eventually solved it. The error message from Apple `This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file is missing or could not be parsed` lead to a detour trying to find flaws in the Info.plist file that describes the app, however there never was any problem with this file!
The problem was that I had *another* file with the same name in a sub folder describing some game content. It was this other file that was parsed by ITC when it rejected my app, not the main one in the root folder. 
By renaming this other file the problem went away. 
Just saying in case someone else can't find any "illegal characters" in their Info.plist file.

Comment: I have used DKImagePickerController using cocoapod and it has created multiple `Info.plist` files in `Pod/DKImagePickerController`, is that what creating problem for me?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and determined it was yet another xcode program bug that caused (or otherwise allowed) it.

The cause was that the Xcode editor allowed a control character to be included in the target > General > Build (a field you must update for each release). I probably typed a backspace or something there, or the Xcode UI stuck some random control character in there.

### Option 1: Delete / Re-add Recent Changes

A quick thing to try (that would have worked for me) would  be to delete then re-add anything you've recently done that affected the Info.plist file.

### Option 2: Use VI in your terminal on Info.plist

I went to launchpad > terminal then used the commands "cd documents", "li", and repeated that until I got into the directory containing the info.plist file. They I typed "vi Info.plist" and it was obvious the bad character because it was a different color.

Then I repeated the archive operation, and then repeated the validation operation, and this time, it worked.

Shame on Apple for yet another Xcode bug.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using your own code to output plist in binary format, make sure that root element comes first in the index table. Although the format supports arbitrary index of the root element, and device loads it successfully, and all validation tests pass, appstore will issue ITMS-90037 if it is not 0.