# This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing or could not be parsed. Please check it for embedded control characters

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

Please help me out with this issue while uploading application to Appstore I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ITMS-90037 The Info.plist file is missing or could not be parsed while app store submittion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288475/itms-90037-the-info-plist-file-is-missing-or-could-not-be-parsed-while-app-store)

Comment: Please check it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288475/itms-90037-the-info-plist-file-is-missing-or-could-not-be-parsed-while-app-store

Comment: i checked this link,but i am not getting what is this exactly "For me, I had a non visible control character in the file. I edited the file using vi and deleted the invalid character and then everything worked."

Answer (score 4):

I experienced similar issue recently - messed with a lot of different things but at the end, the issue was a bad character in the file - which is only visible through an editor like vi. Open the file with vi and then navigate to the bad character if you find one (it usually sticks out like a sore thumb as a different color to the rest of the file) - then hit 'x' to delete it. The type colon on keyboard and 'wq' and hit enter to save and exit. Delete previous archive - archive again and try to validate. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue & I wasted full day looking here and there creating builds and validating them.
I checked my `Info.plist` file & there was no control character.

One property `CFBundleShortVersionString` from `Info.plist` was referring to `$(MARKETING_VERSION)` which had the control character. So kindly check the `Info.plist` file first and then the referencing `variables`.